# Import Excel file to a table of HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, alasql

I have a simple Excel file in my computer at "D:/Book1.xls". I want to import it to make a table and append the table to a `div` tag in my HTML page.

Would you modify my code below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="EUC-KR">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<script src='http://alasql.org/console/alasql.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://alasql.org/console/xlsx.core.min.js'></script>
<script src="./libs/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alasql('select * into html("#res",{headers:true}) \
                  from xlsx("d:/Book1.xls",\
                            {headers:true})');
        alert("end of function")
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="res">res</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to get access of file directly from web page which is not possible. You cannot access any file outside of you browser. For that you have to select the input element of html and after getting the file data you can store it to javascript variable.

```
<script src="alasql.min.js"></script>
<script src="xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<p>Select CSV file to read:</p>
<input id="readfile" type="file" onchange="loadFile(event)"/>
<script>
    function loadFile(event) {
        alasql('SELECT * FROM FILE(?,{headers:true})',[event],function(data){
            console.log(data);
            // You can data to div also.
        });
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment,

Comment: I've cleared my problem just before. It was a very simple and trifling mistake.
The "xlsx()" function can read only "Book1.xlsx" file not "Book1.xls" file.
I've changed .xls file to xlsx file, and the code worked properly.

alasql('select * into html("#res",{headers:true}) \
            from xlsx("Book1.xlsx",  <-- changed the file......

Answer (score 0):

Scripts

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/modules/infragistics.ext_core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/modules/infragistics.ext_collections.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/modules/infragistics.ext_text.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/modules/infragistics.ext_io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/modules/infragistics.ext_ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/modules/infragistics.documents.core_core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/modules/infragistics.ext_collectionsextended.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/modules/infragistics.excel_core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/modules/infragistics.ext_threading.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/modules/infragistics.ext_web.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/modules/infragistics.xml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/modules/infragistics.documents.core_openxml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2018.2/latest/js/modules/infragistics.excel_serialization_openxml.js"></script>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $("#input").on("change", function () {
        var excelFile,
            fileReader = new FileReader();

        $("#result").hide();

        fileReader.onload = function (e) {
            var buffer = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result);

            $.ig.excel.Workbook.load(buffer, function (workbook) {
                var column, row, newRow, cellValue, columnIndex, i,
                    worksheet = workbook.worksheets(0),
                    columnsNumber = 0,
                    gridColumns = [],
                    data = [],
                    worksheetRowsCount;

                // Both the columns and rows in the worksheet are lazily created and because of this most of the time worksheet.columns().count() will return 0
                // So to get the number of columns we read the values in the first row and count. When value is null we stop counting columns:
                while (worksheet.rows(0).getCellValue(columnsNumber)) {
                    columnsNumber++;
                }

                // Iterating through cells in first row and use the cell text as key and header text for the grid columns
                for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnsNumber; columnIndex++) {
                    column = worksheet.rows(0).getCellText(columnIndex);
                    gridColumns.push({ headerText: column, key: column });
                }

                // We start iterating from 1, because we already read the first row to build the gridColumns array above
                // We use each cell value and add it to json array, which will be used as dataSource for the grid
                for (i = 1, worksheetRowsCount = worksheet.rows().count(); i < worksheetRowsCount; i++) {
                    newRow = {};
                    row = worksheet.rows(i);

                    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnsNumber; columnIndex++) {
                        cellValue = row.getCellText(columnIndex);
                        newRow[gridColumns[columnIndex].key] = cellValue;
                    }


                    data.push(newRow);
                }

                // we can also skip passing the gridColumns use autoGenerateColumns = true, or modify the gridColumns array
                createGrid(data, gridColumns);
            }, function (error) {
                $("#result").text("The excel file is corrupted.");
                $("#result").show(1000);
            });
        }

        if (this.files.length > 0) {
            excelFile = this.files[0];
            if (excelFile.type === "application/vnd.ms-excel" || excelFile.type === "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" || (excelFile.type === "" && (excelFile.name.endsWith("xls") || excelFile.name.endsWith("xlsx")))) {
                fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(excelFile);
            } else {
                $("#result").text("The format of the file you have selected is not supported. Please select a valid Excel file ('.xls, *.xlsx').");
                $("#result").show(1000);
            }
        }

    })
});

function createGrid(data, gridColumns) {
    if ($("#grid1").data("igGrid") !== undefined) {
        $("#grid1").igGrid("destroy");
    }

    $("#grid1").igGrid({
        columns: gridColumns,
        autoGenerateColumns: true,
        dataSource: data,
        width: "100%",

    });


}
```

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="input" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />

<div id="result"></div>
<table id="grid1"></table>
```